# Ability of SHFileOperation

Tags: c++, rename, move, shfileoperation

Does SHFileOperation support to move and rename files  at the same time?

I'v got a set of files :
c:\
f1.bmp f2.bmp f3.bmp f4.bmp

I want to move each to new folder, and rename them:
d:\
b1.bmp  b2.bmp b3.bmp b4.bmp

Can I use SHFileOperation? and just do it once?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SHEFILEOPSTRUCT msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759795(VS.85).aspx)

You can use the FOF_MULTIDESTFILES as stated in the msdn article: "The pTo member specifies multiple destination files (one for each source file in pFrom) rather than one directory where all source files are to be deposited." Perform a FO_MOVE operation with this flag.